# How to store Report's descriptions in CodeIgniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, data-storage

I'm writing web project which consists of layout page with different types of reports. I'm using **tooltip ui** so customers can read the description of each report when they hover it, which consist of 6-8 sentences. All report's names are stored in one table `reports` as column `'report name'` with column `'description'`. Each report is a function in my structure. Is it a right way to keep separate description of report from Report's data? Is there are any good practices that I should be aware of? Here is my code:

In Controller:

```
function my_report_name() 
    {
        $data['report_name']=$this->Reports_model->getMyReportNameSummary();
        $data['description_report_name']=$this->Reports_model->getReportDescription('my_report_name');

        //view in 'view/report' folder to use
        //name of view always the same as name of function
        $data['main'] = "report/my_report_name";

        $this->load->vars($data);
        //load template
        $this->load->view('template/t_main_full', $data);
    }
```

In layout page:

```
 <tr>
 <a title="$description_report_name" href="<?= site_url('/reports/my_report_name') ?>">My Report Name</a> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the **Reports_model** method **getReportDescription()** accept as a parameter? You are sending 'my_report_name' which doesn't look correct to me.

```
$data['description_report_name']=$this->Reports_model->getReportDescription(my_report_name);
```

Anyway, checking what

```
Reports_model->getReportDescription()
```

returns would be a good first step.

Comment: Im' sending the name of the function, so I can find description for this function in db table.

Comment: how is it stored in your table? I assume as a string so you should enclose it in single quotes getReportDescription('my_report_name')

Comment: mistyped here in my post. Thanks for notice